# Use of Paranamer in gradle to generate parameter name data

Tags: java, android, gradle, reflection

I am trying to get parameter names of class inside my android application. to supply input to a `help()` method which will print all methods available and its parameter type and names. To get the parameter name, i am trying to use paranamer jar. I added paranamer.jar as a module library and i am able to import and use it. But have no idea on how to plug into gradle in order to **generate parameter name data**. Anyone any help ?
Java code-

```
public void help() {
    Method[] declaredMethods = myclass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer();
    for (Method declaredMethod : declaredMethods) {

        String[] parameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(declaredMethod, false);
//process paranamer.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use their Ant task, Ant is neatly integrated in Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:using_custom_ant_tasks

Should be something like

```
configurations {
    paranamer
}

dependencies {
    paranamer 'com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer-ant:2.8'
}

compileJava.doLast {
    ant.taskdef name: 'paranamer',
                classname: 'com.thoughtworks.paranamer.ant.ParanamerTask',
                classpath: configurations.paranamer.asPath
    ant.paranamer(classdir: destinationDir) {
        source.addToAntBuilder ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet
    }
}
```

I didn't test this, I don't use paranamer, I just made this up from the docs and source. `destinationDir` and `source` are not to be replaced by actual strings, but are the fields of the compile task.

I made this as an additional action to the `compileJava` task instead of an own task, because it modifies the class files produced by the compile task in-place and with a separate task it would involve copying the class files somewhere, running the paranamer and then caring that the modified files are packaged instead of the original files. If the paranamer task would modify the result of the `compileJava` task in-place, it would break incremental building, as then the `compileJava` task would always be out-of-date and run every time. The way I suggest it, it is part of the `compileJava` task and thus is done before the up-to-date check logic and thus should work flawlessly in this regard.

If you have multiple source sets or custom `JavaCompile` tasks and want to modify all of them, it would instead something like:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    it.doLast {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried same by adding the same to app module build.gradle file. Added paranamer-ant, and generator jar as external libraries to my project. , Got it compiled. Everything looks good. But parameter lookup returns null. Something wrong. I am digging more. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `paranamer-generator` is a dependency of `paranamer-ant`, so you don't need to add it explicitly. Are you sure this is supposed to work on Android? Maybe the Android build chain removes again what the generator did?

Comment: I decompiled my final apk and checked, As per paranemer README, If we are using ant paranamer-generator final class file should contain variable `__PARANAMER_DATA`. Unfortunately there is no such variable . I am yet to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe ProGuard throwing out unused fields or something similar? I'm not too familiar with the Android build chain.

Comment: Hey, I figured out the problem. your answer is perfectly correct. I had enabled `Jack` to make JAVA8 as compiler. Paranmer is not working if compiler is JAVA8. As JAVA 8 has inbuilt support to fetch parameter names, Paranmer is ignoring i think(Just my assumption). After removing JAVA8 option to compile worked like charm :). Thank You!

Comment: Java8 support is from Android O. For previous android versions paranamer will help to fetch paramneter data. Added a full app for future users. [HelloWorld app demonstration](https://github.com/rils/Paranamer-Android-Gradle)